# How to debug an Asp.net Core application in Cloud 9

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, cloud

I'm using [Cloud 9](https://ide.c9.io) to develop an ASP.NET Core application.

After configuring the environment and uploading the application, I noticed that I can not debug.

I do not know if I have to add some configuration, package or script to cover some process.

**Characteristics:**

- S.O: Ubuntu 14.04
- RAM: 512MB
- Disk: 2GB

**Packages in use:**

- bower@1.8.0
- generator-aspnet@0.2.5
- grunt-cli@1.2.0
- gulp@3.9.1
- npm@2.15.9
- yo@1.8.5

Comment: We checked in the Cloud documentation that is not supported Debugger for a C # language. Https://docs.c9.io/docs/supported-languages

Comment: Take a look at this video http://www.franksworld.com/2016/08/28/asp-net-core-1-0-on-cloud-9/ and see how to install net core for linux https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu